# How to snap and align an object to the 3d cursors position and rotation?

Tags: modeling

How to snap and align an object to the 3d cursors position and rotation? I’m pretty sure I have done this before and it was straight forward. but I can’t get this to work now at all. Via the shift - S menu I can snap the poistion, but none of the commans affect the rotation.

The align tools don’t seem to want to play nice with the 3d cursor at all.

any suggestions?

Comment: Hello, Beddall. I never knew the 3d cursor has a rotation property.

Comment: yes. In 2.8 you can align it to a surface, or the view, or a custom transform.

Comment: Good to know. I'll stick around to know the answer.

Comment: I found this: https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/aseeu1/blender_28_snapping_to_cursors_rotation/ But I don't have the 2.8 version to check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snap position to cursor will be find in the shift+s menu. To copy the cursor's rotation go to Object>Transform>Align to Transform Orientation and select Cursor in the pop-up menu.
[image]